# Oracle Virtual Box -- How To Connect Host OS To Internet Through Guest OS

Tags: networking, internet, fedora, virtualbox

I have oracle vm virtual box 4.0.12 installed on my fedora 14. In virtual box I have windows XP installed. The windows Xp is connected to internet through a Wimax adapter. How can I connect the Host(fedora) to internet throught the guest Windows XP?

**UPDATE**
The host OS does not have the internet. The guest windows XP connects using a wimax adapter. Unfortunately, the Wimax adapter company does not have drivers for Linux OS. So I cannot use the wimax adapter in host fedora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the Internet Connection Sharing feature of Windows XP, here is a knowledge base article that explains how to configure that for your guest: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

I would recommend setting up a "Host Only Adapter" in the VirtualBox machine configuration and ensure your desktop can communicate properly with it. The connection sharing will likely specify a different set of TCP/IP settings for that adapter than what it defaults to, so you may need to adjust your host to match what the guest configures it as.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking.  Your guest machine connects through the internet using your host's internet connection.  If your host doesn't have internet, I don't believe that your guest would have internet.  Right?

Comment: The host OS does not have the internet. The guest windows XP connects using a wimax adapter. Unfortunately, the Wimax adapter company does not have drivers for Linux OS. So I cannot use the wimax adapter in host fedora

Comment: In other words, dj is using the vbox guest os as a proxy compatibility layer to get hardware to work on an OS that isn't directly supported. It's quite clever and I'm actually trying to do the same thing with an old airgonet adapter that doesn't have Win7 drivers.

Comment: @VictorT. good luck, but I didn't get any success